# Google Drive API Uploading

Tags: upload

Is it possible to use Google Drive API to allow visitors upload files to my Google Drive folder? If yes, any sample codes or demo?
I found sample codes and code library at the link below, but not answered my question.
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

Answer (score 1):

```
Is it possible to use Google Drive API to allow visitors upload files to my Google Drive folder?
 - Yes.
```

***How ?***

By using [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service) you can upload files into your drive by authorizing with your id while uploading file to your drive.

You can read further here : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation